# C# Why is Shell32.Shell.Windows() so slow?

Tags: c#, powershell, shell32

When I try to iterate the file explorer windows in C#.

It takes 7 - 15 seconds to execute the Windows method.

In powershell, it takes less than a second.

What is causing such a long delay?

```
        Shell32.Shell o = new Shell32.Shell();

        // This takes 7 - 15 seconds to execute
        dynamic allWindows = o.Windows();

        for (int i = 0; i < allWindows.count; i++)
        {
            dynamic item = allWindows[i];

            string location = item.LocationURL as string;

            Console.log("Full path", location);
        }
```

Edit:
After more testing. I found that the long call happens when I run this in `protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)` of my WPF application.

However, it doesn't have this long delay if I call it in a STA thread that runs 5 seconds after the application startup.

Comment: What is `Shell32`, exactly? What library/namespace?

Comment: Also, why are you using `dynamic` with what appears to be a strongly-typed library?

Comment: Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation Library. It returns a com object with dynamic members.

Comment: Process Monitor (ProcMon) might be able to reveal what is causing the slowness.  I suspect it may have to do with Internet Explorer startup.  Can you post your PowerShell code for comparison purposes?